# problems with creating new item in nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have nested resources as follows:

employer.rb

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :listings

end
```

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :employer

end
```

I built both using basic scaffold generator.

Everything seems to work except when I create a new listing for employer. The route is

```
new_employer_listing GET
/company/:employer_id/listings/new(.:format)
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"listings"}
```

When I navigate to the new listing url (company/employer_id/listings/new)

I get:

```
NoMethodError in ListingsController#new
undefined method `listing' for #<Employer:0x102dd5e48>
```

Here is the listings_controller code for #new

```
  def new
    @employer = Employer.find_by_username(params[:employer_id])
    @listing = @employer.listing.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @listing }
    end
  end
```

Again, everything else works (show, edit, etc) -- I just can't get a new listing page to come up... Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

//EDIT BELOW

```
  def create
    @employer = Employer.find_by_username(params[:employer_id])
    @listing = @employer.listings.new(params[:listing])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@listing, :notice => 'Listing was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @listing, :status => :created, :location => @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @listing.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

ERROR:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"listings", :id=>#<Listing id: 20, job_title: "asd", location: nil, status: nil, industry: nil, years: nil, degree_type: nil, degree_field: nil, employer_id: 1, employers_id: nil, user_id: nil>}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Employer model you have added the `has_many :listings` association. But in your controller you call `@employer.Listing.new`. The thing that does not match here is Listing and listings.

You should instead do it like this:

```
@listing = @employer.listings.new(params[:listing)
```

Sidenotes:

Don't forget to call `save` on the @listing, otherwise it will not get saved.

I prefer to use `build` instead of `new`, that way the listing is available in the Employer association directly. Both methods valid though depending on how you use them.

Comment: hmm thank you -- I"m geting `No route matches {:controller=>"listings"}` -- any other suggestions? thanks again!

Comment: Quick question, if you have the time: I edited the post with my create definition. After creation occurs, it redirects, but I get an error (also shown above). Any ideas? Thanks for helping a newb :D

Comment: It depends on how your routes look like but if those are correctly nested by using resources and not resource ( common mistake ) then you should be able to do `redirect_to employer_listing_path(@employer, @listing)`

Answer (score 1):

The employer `has_many` listings, so you have to call `@employer.listings`, with an s.

Comment: like this? `@listing = @employer.listings.new` when I do that I get: `No route matches {:controller=>"listings"}` which is interesting because there is a listings controller...strange how everything else works.